# начинающий тестеровщик в Intellij IDEA: как написать код , чтобы дойти до элемента без тупого многоразового "click"

Tags: java

выбран напр.2007 год, а до него "вручную" дойти можно только нажатием на стрелку "вниз" 12 раз (скрола нет). Попытка украсть решение у "Selenium ide" посредством экспорта его кода в свою Intellij IDEA не удалась (и Selenium показал многоразовое нажатие). Как коротко написать, чтоб нашелся нужный год.
Спасибо.[image: вот пример]

Comment: Если _вдруг_ компонент реагирует на ввод с клавиатуры, можно попытаться имитировать нажатия нужных клавиш: 2, 0, 0, 7.

Comment: Спасибо, но, нет, не реагирует, можно только выбрать из предложенного списка